# Trouble installing quantreg package in Fedora

Tags: r, quantreg

I was trying to install the `AER` package and `quantreg` is a dependency, I get the following warning and `AER` is not installed:

```
Warning in install.packages :
   URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/quantreg_5.24.tar.gz': status was '404 Not Found'
```

Then I tried to install `quantreg` and got the same error.

I looked at the URL, and saw that the newest version is `quantreg_5.26`. Can I somehow install this version from Rstudio, or does the `AER` package require the older version? How should I proceed?

I have R version 3.3.0.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884) has many suggestions for package installation issues, maybe useful.

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not cover my problem. I ended up turning off Rstudio and then turning it on again. The R distribution managed by the local IT department had been upgraded, and that seemed to be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to install the dependency first (`quantreg`), then install the package you really want (`AER`).

FWIW, I'm on linux mint, and when I just installed `AER` it didn't even install `quantreg` at all... (granted, I'm not trying to use `AER`, so I don't mind...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have tried that and it doesn't work, same error.

Comment: I'm using Rstudio, perhaps that is enough of a difference.

Comment: I wrote the solution in a comment to my question, but I think that others that stumble upon this might benefit from your answer.